Kafka streams keeps rebalancing
We recently upgraded Kafka streams version to 3.8.0 and are seeing that the streams app keeps rebalancing and does not process any events
We have explicitly set the config
GROUP_INSTANCE_ID_CONFIG

This is what we see on the broker logs:
[GroupCoordinator 2]: Preparing to rebalance group {consumer-group-name} in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 24781 (__consumer_offsets-29) (reason: Updating metadata for static member {} with instance id {}; client reason: rebalance failed due to UnjoinedGroupException)

We also tried to remove the GROUP_INSTANCE_ID_CONFIG but then see these logs and rebalancing and no processing still
sessionTimeoutMs=45000, rebalanceTimeoutMs=1800000, supportedProtocols=List(stream)) has left group {groupId} through explicit `LeaveGroup`; client reason: the consumer unsubscribed from all topics (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

other logs show:
during Stable; client reason: need to revoke partitions and re-join)

client reason: triggered followup rebalance scheduled for 0

On the application logs we see:

state being restored from changelog topic

Task Migrated exceptions
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.TaskMigratedException: Error encountered sending record to topic
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidProducerEpochException: Producer with transactionalId


attempted to produce with an old epoch
Written offsets would not be recorded and no more records would be sent since the producer is fenced, indicating the task may be migrated out; it means all tasks belonging to this thread should be migrated.
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.recordSendError(RecordCollectorImpl.java:306) ~[kafka-streams-3.8.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordCollectorImpl.lambda$send$1(RecordCollectorImpl.java:286) ~[kafka-streams-3.8.0.jar:?]
at
datadog.trace.instrumentation.kafka_clients.KafkaProducerCallback.onCompletion(KafkaProducerCallback.java:44) ~[?:?]

at
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:1106) ~[kafka-clients-3.8.0.jar:?]

